# Instagram Graph API and app approval process

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

So I'm developing this feature called Social Media Wall which is basically setting up and styling this plugin https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed

Everything worked fine until I had to add Instagram - they have switched their previous API off and now I can only get my on posts with it. So I went for the Graph API, followed their guide - added Instagram Product, got verified Business account for both Facebook and Instagram etc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

And now the problem is that I need Public Page Access to get the posts of other public companies, and in order to do that I also need manage_pages permission, which I get denied! They say something like "you app does not need this permission". How can it not need it if it gets added with the Public Page Access!

So it's my fourth review request pending now, when I carefully try to explain what I'm trying to implement, how it works with Facebook already and why I need those permissions.

So I wanted to ask - did someone get this approval before and what did you have to do for it? I'm really desperate now.

Below i the screenshot of the previous answer. They also attached a screenshot of the login page saying that it should help me to understand their response.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AfEM.png]

Comment: not entirely sure, but i believe you can only get media of instagram accounts you own. according to the docs, you need a token for the specific business account.

Comment: btw, that plugin is VERY bad, i hope you don´t use it. access tokens are always meant to be kept secret, that plugin uses them client side, hardcoded. don´t ever do that. also, the issue list is full of "facebook/instagram does not work" issues. it´s not that easy anymore.

Comment: also, doing this server side allows caching, which is very important to avoid api limits

Comment: @luschn thank you for your answers, I am aware that the plugin needs to be improved, that's a second step to make calls server-side and enable caching. As for the business account - my client has one, but that doesn't help much. I contacted the support directly but they weren't very helpful. They say manage_pages is only needed for posting on behalf of other users, which I don't need. But when I apply for the instagram_basic, the interface keeps saying I need to apply for manage_pages. It's a complete mess, I don't know how to proceed

Comment: manage_pages is not for posting, it is for general access to facebook pages (and their connected instagram accounts). so you do need manage_pages too.

Comment: @luschn it's weird, looks like their support doesn't know what is needed for what. Have you ever been approved for the Graph API? How did you record the screencast for them?

Comment: of course, it worked very well. i even got manage_pages and public page content access approved already. are you sure you know when you need public page content access, and when you need manage_pages? there is also 2 different public page content access permissions, for facebook and instagram.

Comment: Yes, I know when I need it as it tells me that I need manage_pages when I select instagram_basic already. Which is a bit odd in fact. But, for Facebook I got approved easily for those permissions (public access and manage pages), my problem now is instagram approval